# Client to DB vs Client to Server to DB

Tags: architecture

I have to choose which way I should create new application: Client-DataBase (with business logic implemented at stored procedures) or Client-Server-DataBase (where business logic is implemented at server side, leaving stored procedures with just data representation functions).

Today there exists stored procedures, that allows to create DB very smart, and argument "client shouldn't have business-logic" is not good: with stored procedures it may not have much of business logic. What for should I create server? Or I don't need it and should try to implement as max as possible on stored procedures side?

If I need to contact many DB's, with server I may do it by async connections. With DB variant I may do it with dblinks (and even also async, as I understand).

Is it question of preferences, or there exists architecture needs and logic that I don't see yet?

Answer (score 1):

Most modern applications make their databases as dumb as possible.  Kicking logic out of them makes an application much more scalable, testable, and portable.

Putting business logic into stored procedures means you must scale your application vertically by making larger and larger databases to support it.

Testing stored procedures is notoriously difficult and expensive compared to testing a standalone business logic layer.

It also tightly couples you to a single database provider.

If none of these are concerns, then putting all of your logic into a stored procedure may be a viable solution.  I've never seen a stored procedure based application that wasn't a mess.  I'm not saying they are inherently evil, but I almost always see them misused, and the resultant ball-of-mud application is usually a scrap-and-rewrite sort of affair.

Regardless, do some reading:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65742/stored-procedures-a-bad-practice-at-one-of-worlds-largest-it-software-consulting

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StoredProceduresAreEvil

http://ask-beta.slashdot.org/story/04/07/30/2324206/stored-procedures---good-or-bad

Comment: Thank you, I've already listed some arguments about that, but you add some that I didn't found and interesting links.

Comment: About vertical scaling, keeping all related data in one database isn't good thing? I mean, anyway we keep one database for one-type entities, so, vertical scaling here is not argument, isn't it?

Comment: If you are using a model layer (server layer), you don't need to keep the entire domain on a single server.  You could put related data on a different server.  For example...  If you have one database for customers, and a different one for customer orders.  You could have your lookup data about customers in a separate store (address, invoice options, logins, etc).  And bring the two stores together in the model layer.  This scales well because the two sources of data have very different usage patterns (high read vs high write), and could be scaled very differently.